# How to enable CORS for specific endpoints using ESPv2 on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, openapi, extensible-service-proxy

currently I have the following code in `openapi.yml.j2`:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  ...
host: {{ deployment_name }}.endpoints.{{ gcloud_project }}.cloud.goog
x-google-endpoints:
- name: {{ deployment_name }}.endpoints.{{ gcloud_project }}.cloud.goog
  allowCors: True
basePath: /
x-google-management:
...
paths:
  /foo
  ...
  
  /bar
  ...
```

This enables CORS for all the paths. Is there a way for me to only allow CORS for foo but not the rest of the endpoints?

I'm not sure if we can do it via ESPv2.